# Google Sheet - compute apr for less than a year old investment

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am trying to convert an excel spread sheet I have kept for over 15 years of investments into Google Sheet, but I am getting a formula error on all purchases I have made that are less than 1 year old.

An example of a formula I am using is **=RATE(G9/12,0,-1*F9,J9,0)**

The numeric values of this formula would be **=RATE(5.57/12,0,-6854,5672,0)**

This should be showing me the APR based on the change so far this year, but instead I am getting the error **"Function rate parameter 1 value is 0. It should be greater than 0."**

Once my purchase is one year or more old, the formula works fine. How can I include the apr of a recent purchase?

Comment: Welcome to Web Apps Stack Exchange! [Take the tour here.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) Would you mind adding a link to your spreadsheet? This will help us figure out the problem.

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. Parameter1 of `RATE` is "number of periods". In your case, 5.57/12 = 0.4464...... That is, the number of periods is **less than 1**. So, the question is, what does "5.57" represent?